# How can I change the UITextAttributes to a new Font Size and Weight?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Here is what has been suggested:

```
UITextAttributes att = new UITextAttributes(); att.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20.0 , FontAttributes.Bold); // size and weight
```

However this gives me an error with the setting of both the number and the font weight.  The number format

```
Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'System.nfloat' (CS1503) 

Error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes' to 'UIKit.UIFontWeight' (CS1503)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First param is an `nfloat`, so add a `f` to the number and the second param is an `UIFontWeight` enum.

#### Example:

```
UITextAttributes att = new UITextAttributes
{
    Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20.0f, UIFontWeight.Bold)
};
```

re: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIFont.SystemFontOfSize/